# How to convert Map to array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm trying to convert a Map into array of object

Lets say I have the following map:

`let myMap = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2);`

And I want to convert the above map into the following:

```
[
   {
      "name": "a",
      "value": "1",
   },
   {
      "name": "b",
      "value": "2",
   }
]
```

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You could take [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and map the key/value pairs.

```js
let map = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2),
    array = Array.from(map, ([name, value]) => ({ name, value }));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: What about converting values to a string using `.toString()`?

Comment: @AsadShakeel, then take the classic approach with key/value for a property: `{ name, value: value.toString() }`

Comment: Ohh!! got it. So the above values are storing as a shorthand property in the object and we can assign the values whatever we want to do. Thanks.

Comment: if you want key value - array = Array.from(map, ([name, value]) => ({ [name]: value }));

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why the parenthesis are needed at `({ name, value })`. What are they doing? When omitted, it returns an `[undefined, undefined]`. Can someone explain?

Comment: @dmathisen, with arrow functions, that is the shorthand for returning an object.
    ```(name, value) => ({ name, value })```
is the same as
    ```(name, value) => { return { name, value } }```

Comment: @dmathisen, without braces, it is a block statement.

Answer (score 52):

Use [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let myMap = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2);

const arr = [...myMap].map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value }));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: In most of the cases the key is allready embeeded in the value so we dont need that. ( when storing an array of objects)

Comment: Typescript doesn't like the [...myMap] syntax: "TS2569: Type 'Map ' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators."

Comment: @Roman [It seems that you're targeting es5](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6842#issuecomment-178872658), you have to add `downlevelIteration: true` to `compilerOptions`

Answer (score 9):

with  spread of ES6 like this:

```js
let myMap = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2);

const  result = Array.from(myMap).map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply iterate over the `Map` object using any compatible iteration method and add each item as an object to the resulting array.

For example, you can use `Map.prototype.forEach()` in the following way:

```
const myMap = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2);
const arr = [];

myMap.forEach((value, name) => arr.push({ name, value }));

console.log(arr);
```

Or, as an alternative, you may use the `for...of` loop like so:

```
const myMap = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2);
const arr = [];

for (const [name, value] of myMap) {
    arr.push({ name, value });
}

console.log(arr);
```

Wrote a [blog post](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-convert-javascript-map-to-array-of-objects) explaining different methods for those who're interested in learning more.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple I will explain in steps:

1. [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) a map into an array of arrays.

```js
const map = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2).set('c', 3)
const mapArr = [...map] // array of arrays
```

2. Map each subarray as `key`-`value` pairs. `map` function returns a new array containing `object` of `key`-`value` pairs.

```js
const arr = mapArr.map(([key, value]) => ({key, value}))
```

** Remember: ** the name we use for mapping the data will be the name of the object mapped in this case `key` and `value`.

One liner:

```js
const map = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2).set('c', 3)
const arr = [...map ].map(([key, value]) => ({key, value}))
console.log({arr})
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6  [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)  syntax only :

```
const myMap = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2);
const arr = [...myMap];
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll got : **[ { key: 'a', value: 1 }, { key: 'b', value: 2 } ]**

if instead, you use the following line :

```
    const arr = [...map ].map(([key, value]) => ([key]: value}));
```

You will have the following result : **[ {a: 1}, {b: 2} ]**

Comment: The code is incorrect, because of the missing `{` and `}` but even then, it's not what OP wanted. The result is`[ {a: 1}, {b: 2} ]` while they wanted `[ {name: 'a', value: 1}, {name: 'b', value: 2} ]`.