# Render Component in Map.foreach

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to render a component for every item in my Map Object, grouped is typed as

> Map<string, Invite[]> | undefined

.map is not an option here, Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Map<string, PactInvite[]>'.  Foreach is but this does not return the div or component. How can I render the items in a foreach?

```
  const PendingInvitesView = (props: PendingInvitesProps) => {
  const { refetchPactsProfiles, onClickPreviewProfile, grouped } = props
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  return (
    <div className={styles['invite-section']}>
      <Accent className={styles['invite-section-title']}>{t('agenda.invites.title')}</Accent>
      <Space style={{ width: '100%' }} size="small" direction="vertical">
        <>
          {grouped?.forEach((element) => {
            element.length > 1 ? (
              <div>test</div>
            ) : (
              <InviteCard
                onClickPreviewProfile={onClickPreviewProfile}
                refetchPactsProfiles={refetchPactsProfiles}
                invite={element[0] as Invite}
              />
            )
          })}
        </>
      </Space>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should replace `forEach` curly braces {} with normal braces ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot render items using `forEach` because return value of this method is `undefined`.
I propose you convert the `Map` into array before you do rendering part. Then you should use `map` method.

[Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795743/how-to-convert-map-to-array-of-object) how to do it.